# parrent armature bone to 3 vertecies of a different mesh

Tags: bones, vertices, parent, pose-mode

How to parent armature bone in pose mode to 3 vertices of a mesh

Because parenting a single atmature bone through object mode works fine,
but trying to accomplish the same result witch constraints in pose mode seams to be broken.
weather by child of or copy transform :/

Comment: Why in pose mode? What advantage do you get?

Comment: Because I need a LOT of them. and having that many armatures or anything will get in the way

Comment: But how will pose mode change the amount of armatures in your scene? Can you clarify a little bit more?

Comment: Because one armature can have many bones in it and they can be edited all at the same time and easily found within that one armature. Less objects in collections.

Comment: So, do you just want a way to parent 3 separate vertices to a bone? You don't need pose mode to do that.

Comment: No, the other way around. I wish to parent the bone to those vertices.

Comment: Parenting the bone to the vertices means that if you move the vertices, the bone moves with them, This is very unusual, because bones are there to move vertices. Why would you want this?

Comment: I'm making wings. And I need the little feathers to be controllable but also follow the skin of the wings that is already deformed by another armature. Its weight painted smoothly

Comment: But why would you want the vertices to move with the bones?

Comment: the birds hand mesh morphs correctly. I need the feathers to follow

Comment: Please add a picture, I am having a lot of trouble understanding.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/UJRZZqj.mp4

Comment: I need to fill in the white area with feathers. I already tried to parent some of the feathers to the empty over there. But Id rather if the bones did not need the empties

Comment: So if you want to parent the bone to the feathers (meaning that if you move the bone, you move the feathers) then why don't you jsut create a vertex group with the vertices that you want, and name it after the bone you want it to be moved by.

Comment: No I need the bone to follow the vertices on the hand mesh. feathers will follow the bones. I don't want to parent the bones to the feathers

Comment: I think I get it now:
Create a vertex group on every place that you want a feather.
Take bone, use a copy location constraint on the bone, and choose the wing and the correct vertex group. Then you can use whatever constraints you want (copy location, rotation, scale,) and put it on the feather, so that the feather moves with the bone. 

You could cut out the middleman and just parent the feather to the vertex group rather than the bone, but that's your choice.

Comment: Parenting the feathers to the vertex group would work but I plan to export the animation to unreal engine so it has to be armature animated

Comment: How can I add a small blend file as an example?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fhayedor97v8ute/comparison.blend?dl=0

Comment: Here's the issue properly seen. You can compare them by moving vertices. I need both the rotation and location to adjust to the warping like the object mode one. It would be best if it could average out between 4 points but I doubt that's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To strictly answer the question: Easiest thing is to parent an empty to the mesh vertices, then copy transforms from that empty.  (And probably limit scale, because vertex triangle parenting leaves you with some pretty gigantic skew problems that you probably don't want...)

Alternative, without any empty, is to copy location from a vertex group marked vertex, damped track another vertex group marked vertex, and then locked track a third vertex group marked vertex.  (Copy transform or rotation from vertices is never a good idea.)

However, most of the time people ask this question or one like it, they're trying to do something impossible.  They're trying to acquire this position and then use it to further deform the same mesh that they're "parented" to.  You can't do that-- it's a dependency loop.  The mesh depends on the bone which depends on the mesh which depends on....  The end goal of people asking this *may* be achievable, but this particular technique is not a means of achieving it (and the technique that works is likely to be complicated, possibly involving dummy copies of the mesh.)

Comment: :D thank u very much!